# What is the default http2 write buffer size (grpc.http2.write_buffer_size)?

Tags: grpc, grpc-c++

`grpc::ClientWriterInterface::Write()` internally writes to a `http2` stream. From gRPC documentation, it appears that the buffer size of this stream is controlled by `GRPC_ARG_HTTP2_WRITE_BUFFER_SIZE` or `grpc.http2.write_buffer_size`, [see here](https://grpc.github.io/grpc/core/group__grpc__arg__keys.html#ga8ee81850446e587a7410df5ab640c565).

This [performance notes](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/035d27924bf0c9b1d069e823e1df1da34babf151/doc/cpp/perf_notes.md) also talk about this channel argument.

However, I could not find what is the default value of this parameter/configuration. How to know the same? Also how do I use a custom value for the same?

Answer (score 1):

The default value is currently 65535 bytes. But that is an internal detail which may change. You can see how it's used here https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/867973b4c0915e39b6eff17618754978ab91a4d6/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/chttp2_transport.cc#L374-L376

To set a custom write buffer size, you can create a custom channel using ChannelArguments, something like:

```
grpc::ChannelArguments args;
args.SetInt(GRPC_ARG_HTTP2_WRITE_BUFFER_SIZE, 32768);
auto channel = grpc::CreateCustomChannel(..., args);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like gRPC documentation does not mention anywhere the default value of this (`GRPC_ARG_HTTP2_WRITE_BUFFER_SIZE`) or any channel argument; and one has to grep the source code to find the default values.

For the version we're using (`v1.43.2`) I found it to be `64kB`, [here](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/v1.43.2/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/chttp2_transport.cc):

```
#define MAX_WRITE_BUFFER_SIZE (64 * 1024 * 1024)
...
...
} else if (0 == strcmp(channel_args->args[i].key,
                           GRPC_ARG_HTTP2_WRITE_BUFFER_SIZE)) {
      t->write_buffer_size = static_cast<uint32_t>(grpc_channel_arg_get_integer(
          &channel_args->args[i], {0, 0, MAX_WRITE_BUFFER_SIZE}));
}
```